# what is the difference between these two piece of json

Tags: json, wcf

Before we rewrote the system to use a wcf service the json returned to the client is :

```
{"CreationDate":"2016-12-01T13:15:02.923+00:00","Email":"sagysad@dd.com","IsApproved":true,"IsLockedOut":false,"IsOnline":true,"LastActivityDate":"2017-03-31T00:13:21.333+01:00","LastLockoutDate":"1754-01-01T00:00:00+00:00","LastLoginDate":"2017-03-31T00:13:21.113+01:00","LastPasswordChangedDate":"2099-12-31T00:00:00+00:00","ProviderName":"LoginProvider","ProviderUserKey":"dcc5f38f-f71e-4d9d-bdb2-58fb60b7a65e","UserName":"schoi","IsValidLogin":true}
```

but after exposing it as a wcf service the json has changed to this:

```
{
    "SignInResult":
    {
        "CreationDate": "/Date(1480598102923+0000)/",
        "Email": "steven.choi@dasdada.com",
        "IsApproved": true,
        "IsLockedOut": false,
        "IsOnline": true,
        "IsValidLogin": true,
        "LastActivityDate": "/Date(1490916050417+0100)/",
        "LastLockoutDate": "/Date(-6816268800000+0000)/",
        "LastLoginDate": "/Date(1490916050417+0100)/",
        "LastPasswordChangedDate": "/Date(-2208988800000+0000)/",
        "ProviderName": "LoginProvider",
        "ProviderUserKey": "dcc5f38f-f71e-4d9d-bdb2-58fb60b7a65e",
        "UserName": "schoi"
    }
}
```

why can't I just do this

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignInResult>((provider.SignIn(username,password))
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), `DateTime` objects are:

> ...represented in JSON as "/Date(number of ticks)/". The number of
>   ticks is a positive or negative long value that indicates the number
>   of ticks (milliseconds) that have elapsed since midnight 01 January,
>   1970 UTC.

if you want deserilze it with newsoft you can use this:

```
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignInResult>((provider.SignIn(username,password), settings )
```

Comment: good to know but I have since changed it to tuse datacontractserializer class from ms